# SQL query joining two different tables. Find online status from user's last interaction

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Problem description: Finding online status of therapist users based on  last interaction in `Session` table. Cannot keep last interaction date on `User` table but it should be separated on `Session` table. But how can I join one row for each user with `User` table information and session data of `Session` table for user's last interaction for each record?

[image: Problem showing online status of Therapists]

Description of figure 1: Listing of therapists from User table with showing their online status based on their last interaction from Session table

[image: Table1 = **User** email is the primary key here]

Description of figure2 (User): **User** table is the first table and **email** is its primary key. It need to be joined with second column, that is **Session** table's **StartDate** field as one row for each record. (Pink backgrounded `StartDate` column is not on `User` table. `User` table columns plus the pink backgrounded `StartDate` column is desired result)

The hardest part of the problem is `email` is basis of join field and only one in `User` table but has many in the `Session` table because it is not primary there.

[image: Table2 = **Session** notice that email key duplicates as per user interacts]

Description of figure3 (Session): Email field duplicates as user interacts in the program. They are kind of logs of key presses changing personal information e.g.

I cannot created a qualified query to solve my problem so I created a query for table1 and second query in the loop that is not right way of doing the job. It caused performance issues. I need to get help joining two different queries at once.

The first query filters results based on primary key `email` from **User** table. The second query gets latest session date on from **Session** table within the loop.

`$marker_list` is the first query and `$sql_online` is for the second query which is nested.

```
<?php

$latitude = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "latitude", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$longitude = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "longitude", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$start = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "start", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

include_once "./connect-db.php";

if ($start == 'undefined') {
    $start = 0;
} else {
    $start = $start * 10;
}
$distance = 100;
//First query: lists therapists from User table
$marker_list = "SELECT `User`.`uid`, `User`.`latitude`, `User`.`longitude`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`phone_verified`, `User`.`email`, ( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(" . $latitude . ")) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(" . $longitude . ")) + sin(radians(" . $latitude . ")) * sin(radians(latitude ))) ) AS `distance` FROM `massage`.`User` WHERE rol= 'terapist' AND list_on_maps= '1' AND email_valid='1' HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY distance LIMIT $start, 7";

if ($results = mysqli_query($conn, $marker_list)) {
     $sizeofquery = mysqli_num_rows($results);
     $counter = 0; 
     $maps = array();
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results)) {
         $maps[$counter] = new stdClass();
         $maps[$counter]->index = $row[0];
         $maps[$counter]->latlng = new stdClass();
         $maps[$counter]->latlng->latitude = floatval($row[1]);
         $maps[$counter]->latlng->longitude = floatval($row[2]);
         $maps[$counter]->title = $row[3];
         $maps[$counter]->phone_verified = $row[4];
//Second query gets their user interaction from Session table        
         $sql_online= "SELECT `StartDate` FROM `massage`.`Session` WHERE `email`='$row[5]' ORDER BY `Session`.`StartDate` DESC LIMIT 1";
         $result_nested= mysqli_query($conn, $sql_online);
         $row_online= mysqli_fetch_array($result_nested);
         $delta= (strtotime("now") - strtotime($row_online['StartDate']));
         if ($delta < 300 ) {
             $maps[$counter]->online = "y";
         } else if ( $delta < 600){
             $maps[$counter]->online = "t";
         } else {
             $maps[$counter]->online = "g";
         }
         $counter++;
    }
    $maps->counter = $row['counter'];
    $mapsJSON = json_encode($maps);
}
//Third Query: Inserts last interaction as listing therapists as on many pages. It is not an important part of the question.
$sql_session = "INSERT INTO `massage`.`Session` (`StartDate`, `email`, `Interaction`) VALUES (current_timestamp(), '$email', 'dolistmaps');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql_session);
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo $mapsJSON;
mysqli_free_result($results);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

So please help me creating a single query which accomplishes joining two different tables on the common field  `email` on both tables.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: you want to join on basis of `User`.`email` and `Session`.`email` ?

Comment: @RonakDhoot yes, I want to join basis of User.email and Session.email

Comment: @Dharman thank you, I am now studying prepared statements and will update all my code in the project after learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX` to find the latest `StartDate` from `Session` for each email in a derived table and `JOIN` that to the user table to get the results you need:

```
SELECT `User`.`uid`,
       `User`.`latitude`,
       `User`.`longitude`,
       `User`.`name`,
       `User`.`phone_verified`,
       `User`.`email`,
       ( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(" . $latitude . ")) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(" . $longitude . ")) + sin(radians(" . $latitude . ")) * sin(radians(latitude ))) ) AS `distance`,
       s.StartDate
FROM `massage`.`User`
JOIN (
    SELECT email, MAX(StartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM `massage.Session`
    GROUP BY email
) s ON s.email = `User`.email
WHERE rol= 'terapist' AND list_on_maps= '1' AND email_valid='1'
HAVING distance < $distance 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT $start, 7
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SQL` syntax for joining two tables is using `JOIN` keyword. Two tables with a common column could be joined with this syntax:

```
select StartDate
from Masage.Session masag
inner join User user on masag.email = user.email
```

This is for `inner join`. If you want `left outer join` or `right outer join`, or maybe `full outer join` or even `cross join` you shall replace the join cause with a proper keywords. I hope I did answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot but your response is too generic for me. I tried but cannot figure out how to create query. This is my fault but thank you any way.

Comment: @EnginYilmaz You probably should read a `how to ask a good question` section on `dba.stackexchange`. Here is the link https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Others may have a spare time to decifer your code as it is, without sample data and expected output. But I'm too busy right now. Sorry.

Comment: @EnginYilmaz Thanks, Engin. Please pay attention that the `DBA` community expects a few things included in a question. The sample data, the database layout(if needed), and the expected output. Your question ***may*** get a faster answer, if you had supplied the above conditions.